# Camel capture route started by userID

Tags: apache-camel

Is there an option in apache camel to derive the userid, if the route is started manually via Jconsole?

Basically, I have defined an retry route for exceptions that has to be manually triggered. I would like to capture the user detail for audit purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could **add authentification to JConsole**, here is the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html).
But I don't know if you can log user's activity with that method.

However you can use [route policy](http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html) to start or stop route and use [spring-securty](http://camel.apache.org/spring-security.html). With that tools you can **build camel routes to manage routes with authentification** and log whatever info you want on users.